# Automatically adding apps/models to Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm creating a GUI for creating/editing models within the admin interface, see [Github project](https://github.com/timothyclemans/django-admin-models-editor). When a person creates a new app I want that app automatically added to the admin interface and any models in that app. How do I automatically do that?

[image: Embedded model creator/editor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a source code editor, maybe based on [django-alto](https://github.com/jkocherhans/alto) which already has edition for view code, or do a ModelModel that is [loaded dynamically](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels) in which case you might want to base on [django-not-eav](http://django-not-eav.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

The advantage of django-not-eav's approach is that it should be easier to use than source code editing for the average webmaster/website admin.

Either way, it's going to be quite some work :)

Comment: When someone creates an app with startapp its not automatically added to the admin. Is there a way to have it automatically added?

Comment: Either create admin.py and call admin.autodiscover() again, either call admin.site.register() by yourself.

Comment: Thanks! Right now app only shows up if it has models. Is there way to have an app show up even if no models?

Comment: In admin. I would like each app listed on the admin page even if no models so when the user clicks on the app they can add a model to that app.

Comment: For that I would override admin/index.html